# What is a good framework for deploying a portable HTML/JavaScript Windows application?

Tags: windows, user-interface, portability

I need to deploy an application onto some Windows machines for purposes of data collection from a group of people (i.e. the application will be used to gather responses to a series of survey questions). The process is interactive, alternating between displays of text and images with specific timing requirements. I have put together a prototype application using HTML and JavaScript that implements the survey. However, there are some unique constraints on the deployment environment that have me stuck:

- While the machine is Internet-connected, the client requires that the survey application must run fully local to the PC that it runs on. Therefore, sending the survey results to a remote server is not permissible. Obviously, saving to a local file from a Web browser is typically not permitted for security reasons.
- Installation of applications onto the machines that will run the survey is not permitted.
- The configuration of the machines is not known specifically *a priori*, but I can assume some recent version of Windows with IE8+.

The "no remote access" requirement was a late comer, and has thrown a wrench into the plan of just writing a simple Web application that could post results to an HTTP server. I'm now looking for the easiest way forward. Two main approaches come to mind:

1. Use a GUI framework that provides a control that can display HTML/JavaScript; running a full-blown application on the PC would allow me to save the results to the filesystem. I've never done this, but it seems like in this day and age it shouldn't be too difficult. This would allow me to reuse much of my existing prototype implementation, but I would need some way of transferring the results (which would be stored in a JavaScript data structure) outside of the Web control to where the rest of the application could access it.
2. Reimplement the entire application using some GUI framework (I've used PyQt successfully before, although not on Windows). This approach is obviously less desirable than #1 due to the lack of reuse. However, it may be necessary if #1 isn't feasible.

Any recommendations for the best way to go? Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that can be run in a "portable" manner from a USB thumbdrive or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [HTML Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) (HTA)? They work in IE5+ and can use Windows Scripting Host to [write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.84%29) to local drives and UNC shares...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a portable web server with a scripting language on the server side. http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/ Mongoose, for example, you can run PHP, CGI, etc. .. scripts. Then, simply create a script to save a file to your hard drive. And let the rest of the application in the same manner.

Use a script to start the web server, and perhaps a portable web browser like K-Meleon to start the application http://kmeleon.sourceforge.net/ This is highly configurable. Or start the system explorer to your localhost URL.

The only problem may be that the user has to modify the firewall for the first time you run the server?

Comment: Looks like a good solution. I accepted the other answer because it looks like it will get me to where I need to go with slightly less work. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the HTA, seems a better solution. I used the k-meleon to the webserver to develop an interactive CD. you're welcome